# Sublime Text2 how to replace with parameter?

Tags: regex, editor, sublimetext

I have a text like: "test 1 test 2 test 3" and i want to replace to something like: "test d1 test d2 test d3", for this i think that i can use a regex: "\d" and then in the replace use "d(parameter)" so i can catch the number 1, 2 and 3. it is possible in sublime text 2 like is in  notepad++ or editplus?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Ctrl + H (Replace...) you should enable Regular expression (Alt+R) and then you should use

```
\d+
```

in Find What and

```
d$0
```

in Replace With

Comment: You shouldn't need the group if you're using `$0`.

Answer (score 3):

Sublime is a prety recent editor AFAIK so it will have a decent regex engine on board lets hope

Your question is maybe a simplification and I think I read that you want to replace test plus a number with the same thing but prefix it with a d

regex

```
test (\d+)
```

replace with

```
test d$1
```

If they need to come in groups of 3 its rather easy to tweak. Let us know if you can go ahead.